# How to run a rake task every time a record in a model changes? (best practice)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, cron, rake

I want to run a cron rake task every time a record is updated - i.e. some time after the new record is created/updated, a cron rake task will do some processing on the record and save the results.

However, this task is processor intensive and it makes sense to run it only when the record is updated by the user.

What is the best way programmatically to determine if the rake task has already processed a specific record (and the user has not changed it at all)?

I'm thinking of generating a hash for each record and using it to see if it has changed. **There must be a more efficient way to perform this.**

Thanks for the help,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use DelayedJob rather than Cron/Whenever.

Anyway, don't you think it would be better to do it in validation or as before/after save filter? If you implemented this functionality as before_save filter, then you could use dirty attributes. More about dirty attributes you can find here: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm not sure dirty attributes will do the job, I'll give you an example (see below):

Comment: Users can set the appearance of a 'pages' -ex. change colors.
A background job needs to take a snapshot of this page, using an external API. I can run this task with Delayed Job, after each update, but users may test numerous color combinations before settling at one. If I use DJ, my app will invoke several background jobs complicating things a lot. I was thinking that the most efficient approach is to run a scheduled task every 3-4 hours, check for updates in a record and then run the task. If a record is unchanged, skip the whole job as it has already been run.
Any ideas?